# Density values of histogram in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, histogram, density-plot

In base R, we can use the function `hist()` to create the density histogram of a given variable, say `x`. If we write:

```
  h <- hist(x, freq=FALSE)
```

then, `h$mids` is a vector containing the mid-point value for each bin, and `h$density` contains the density for each bin. I want to draw my density histogram with **ggplot2** with `geom_histogram()`.

Is there any way to retrieve the similar values (mid-point and density of each bin) from the **ggplot2** functions?

Comment: What about using `geom_density()`?

Comment: You can also change the scale on your histogram to give density values (instead of the default "count") via `geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..))`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. It just generates a density histogram. My question is how can I retrieve the midpoints of each bin and the density value for each bin by using the ggplot2 functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this by creating a histogram using `ggplot() + geom_histogram()`, and then use `ggplot_build()` to extract the bin midpoints, min and max values, densities, counts, etc.

Here's a simple example using the built-in `iris` dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)

# make a histogram using the iris dataset and ggplot()
h <- ggplot(data = iris) +
  geom_histogram(mapping = aes(x=Petal.Width),
                 bins = 11)

# extract the histogram's underlying features using ggplot_build()
vals <- ggplot_build(h)$data[[1]]

# print the bin midpoints
vals$x
## 0.00 0.24 0.48 0.72 0.96 1.20 1.44 1.68 1.92 2.16 2.40

# print the bin densities
vals$density
## 0.1388889 1.0000000 0.2500000 0.0000000 0.1944444 0.5833333 0.5555556 0.5000000 0.3055556 0.2500000 0.3888889
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. That's very helpful. I could also manage the situation by using the R function density(). For the above example, we may write d<-density(iris$Petal.Width); then, d$x returns the bin midpoints, and d$y returns the densities.